# Ansible user-interactive module while running shell script

Tags: ansible

I am new to ansible and trying to learn basic things...

I am trying to execute a below shell script with ansible...This script has case condition included which needs a user input. But while running in ansible, it's not asking anything and completing a task. I want my ansible to ask a i/p during executing and accordingly execute the script.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Execute the script
    shell: /usr/bin/sh /root/ansible_testing/testing.sh
```

snippet of shell script is...

```
 echo "Press 1 for Backup"
 echo "Press 2 for MakeChange"
 echo "Press 3 for Keepsafe"
 echo "*******************************************"

 echo -n "Enter your choice : "
 read choice2

 case $choice2 in
 1)

   echo "Hello"
```

Answer (score 9):

There's a bunch of ways you can do this with just bash (there's a pretty good answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/338860/710917)).  However if you want to accomplish this the Ansible way you could use the [expect module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html).

```
- name: Execute the script
  expect:
    command: /usr/bin/sh /root/ansible_testing/testing.sh
    responses:
      "Enter your choice": "1"
```

In this example, `Enter your choice` is the regex ansible will match on to input a "1".  If there are multiple prompts that use `Enter your choice` Ansible will input a "1" for all of them.